# On which principle does string telephone work?

Tags: acoustics, string

I am 15 yrs old. and I got the work to find about [string telephone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone) and make a project. I search google a lot but can't find the exact principle.

What I found is the 1st person having the one cup speak in the cup and another person with his cup on his ear can listen. But I want to know on which sound principle does it work?

Please help me fast . 
In advance thanks all of them who helped me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic principle is the conversion of acoustic vibrations into vibrations that travel through the string. Sound travels faster through solids than through the air, which makes this method better for longer distances.

When you speak into your cup, the bottom of the cup vibrates like a diaphragm. These vibrations are converted into longitudinal vibrations which travel along the string, and when they reach the other cup, they cause the bottom of that cup to vibrate like a diaphragm, as acoustic vibrations, audible to the person at the other end.

In landline telephones, the acoustic vibrations are instead converted to electrical currents (coded) and then decoded into acoustic vibrations at the other end, which means that they can be used over even longer distances, provided that there is a wired connection for the current to flow.

Do keep in mind that string telephones work only when the string is kept taut so that the vibrations are conveyed from one cup to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does there any specific type of vibration that travels through the string.

Comment: Longitudinal vibrations are set up in the string due to acoustic waves which are longitudinal pressure waves. Longitudinal waves are those which vibrate in the direction of propagation, unlike transverse waves which vibrate perpendicular to the direction of propagation of the wave.

Comment: can you please tell me , which string is used to make string telephone ?

Comment: Any string should do, as long as you hold it taut. Thicker strings like jute strings can help you transmit messages at distances of about 30m. Below that cotton strings would do.

Comment: dont use metal strings, maybe best ones are thoes for knitting...and maybe use plastic cups...

Answer (score 0):

The sound pressure waves move the bottom of the cup. If the string is taut, then a longitudinal tension wave will travel along the string. When it gets to the second cup, the string will pull on the bottom of the cup, vibrating it in the same way that the original cup vibrated. The vibrating bottom will cause pressure waves in the cup, which will travel to your ears.

And then the receiver hears the sound.

If you don't hold the string taut, the sound wave will not travel.